# Dynamically change the src of a script tag

Tags: javascript

I've read some of the similar questions but they don't quite answer this query of mine.

I am building a website that uses Viddler video hosting. In their embed code you recieve a script tag, like this:

```
<script src="http://www.viddler.com/tools/vidget.js?widget_type=js_list&amp;widget_width=940&amp;source=playlist&amp;user=USERNAME&amp;playlist=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;style=grid&amp;show_player=true&amp;player_type=simple&amp;max=12&amp;videos_per_row=6&amp;v=2.0&amp;id=XXXXXXXXXX" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I have x'd out my client's ID, but the bit I am interested in changing dynamically is the playlist.

Viddler suggested just using a tabbed container to house all of the video playlists, but I am not so comfortable with having that amount of coding on the page if I don't need it.

My workaround is to somehow use buttons to change the script source or just the `playlist=` variable.

Does anyone have any ideas on how this could be achieved?

Comment: That "source" variable is a request parameter that is sent when the script is *fetched*  from the server - the only way to change it would be refetching the whole viddler code again (probably not something you want)

Comment: Well the embed code includes a div container and its components that contain the videos and playlist. Plus the scripts that call them into that container. Yeah ideally I didnt want to have to call the whole thing again and again, but just the script src and/or playlist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery you can [load and execute JavaScript on demand](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/). Before loading the script, append the playlist part to the script url like this:

**HTML**

```
<a href="playlisturl" class="playlist-link">Play list A</a>
<a href="playlisturl" class="playlist-link">Play list B</a>
<a href="playlisturl" class="playlist-link">Play list C</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".playlist-link").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var playlist = $(this).attr("href");

    var url = 'http://www.viddler.com/tools/vidget.js' +
                  '?widget_type=js_list' +
                  '&widget_width=940' +
                  '&source=playlist' +
                  '&user=USERNAME ' +
                  '&playlist='+ playlist +
                  '&style=grid'+
                  '&show_player=true'+
                  '&player_type=simple'+
                  '&max=12'+
                  '&videos_per_row=6'+
                  '&v=2.0'+
                  '&id=XXXXXXXXXX';

    $.getScript(url, function(data, textStatus){
        alert('This is executed after your script is loaded');
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow not too far off what I was attempting to do. So just to run through what this is doing; when a link with a class of .playlist-link is clicked, we run the function (e) - function (e) is then fetching the script and all its variables.

Comment: How would I implement this if I I had say 10 different playlists? I presume I would be creating another version of this for each one and changing the class name and '&playlist='

Comment: What is the alert for? - Do I need the alert?

Comment: you replace the alert with what ever code you want to run after script is loaded, lets say play() or something related to the player..

Comment: Thank you very much, this is perfect. I will be emailing you as I require some additional help.

Comment: Hmm I can't seem to email you. Perhaps you could email me: info@blandydoes.co.uk - I need some help creating a smoother user experience, and I will need to set a default playlist to show before the user selects another.

Comment: you should ask question here at stackoverflow, not by private mail ;)

Comment: Default playlist has been created so that is fine, but is there a way of creating a smoother transition between the playlists?

Comment: Um not really sure how to explain it, when you transition from one video to the next it feels very sudden, immediate reaction. There are video players out there that will fade in the videos in the playlist using animations and the like. This is way more work than what I would expect you to achieve here though, hence why I was wanting to discuss it outside of stack overflow. Unless of course its just a simple case of adding a few lines of code? ;-p

Comment: Maybe just a loading.gif needs to be present when transitioning between the video playlists?