# Dynamically change google maps script src with select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I want to change the Google maps script src when one of my dropdown options is clicked because I'm having an issue when searching for zip codes on my page. To get the correct result I believe I need to use Google's Region Localization "&region=" in the src url.(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Localization)

I've loaded my google maps api within the `<head>` tag:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>`

I've created a drop down list

```
<select id="country">  
   <option value="sel">Select</option>
   <option value="DK">Denmark</option>
   <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
   <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
</select>
```

I want the google maps script src to change whenever one of the options is clicked on.

For example: If I click on Denmark, the src would then change to:
`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&region=DK`

I've tried some stuff out by looking through this [Dynamically change the src of a script tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295394/dynamically-change-the-src-of-a-script-tag)
but I still can't figure out how to make it work.

At the moment I have this:

```
$('#country option').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var region = $(this).attr('value');
    var url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&region=' + region;
});
```

I'm really newbie when it comes to jQuery and javascript so I thought maybe I could get some help in here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't do it like that, because removing a script-element doesn't remove the methods,variables etc. that have been created by the script. You will receive a warning like that:

*Warning: you have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors*

Instead you should use the region-parameter inside the requests, e.g. when geocoding

Comment: Okay I see... But if I then wanted to save the user's region from the selected option in the dropdown menu, how would I do that? Right now `geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address, 'region': 'DK' }` works. So I suppose changing 'DK' with a variable region would work, but first I need to save some data in the variable, but I don't know how :/

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to dynamically load a new script for your page based on a user selection then you might want to take a look at [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/). Just trying to change the value of that element wouldn't make a different because it's already been loaded for your page.

Actually, if your desired script is entirely dependent on the user selection in the dropdown I would suggest removing it from the page entirely and just loading it after the user makes a choice only.